# contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I have managed to use one array to as my datasource to create messages in the `firebasechat`. I can send messages at the moment. However I would like to show messages in my `tableview` from the top. When I tried `scrollToRow`, it doesn't work. If I take it out, messages can be sent, but don't update in the `tableview`. Here is my output.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:]: row (9) beyond bounds (9) for section (0).'

```
var tableObjects: [String] = []

@IBAction func sendButton(_ pSender: UIButton) {
            generateMessages()
      }

private func generateMessages() {
                let userReference = userReference(userID: AppDelegate.shared.user!.userID, fullName: AppDelegate.shared.user!.fullName, status: .buddy)
                guard let stringText = textField.text else { return }
                let message = AppDelegate.shared.userMessages[stringText]
                let addMessage = "\(AppDelegate.shared.addMessage(stringText, to: self.conversation!, sender: userReference, type: .text, date: message?.date))"
                self.tableObjects.append(addMessage)
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.tableObjects.count - 1, section: 0)
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
                self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
                textField.text = nil
            }

func numberOfSections(in pTableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

func tableView(_ pTableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection pSection: Int) -> Int {
            return self.tableObjects.count
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let row = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                let theCell = pTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reUseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
                return theCell
            }

func objectAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> String {
            return self.tableObjects[indexPath.row]
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

it is simple, you are trying to scroll before the tableview endUpdates, you must place

```
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

before

```
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

your code should look like

```
private func generateMessages() {
    let userReference = userReference(userID: AppDelegate.shared.user!.userID, fullName: AppDelegate.shared.user!.fullName, status: .buddy)
    guard let stringText = textField.text else { return }
    let message = AppDelegate.shared.userMessages[stringText]
    let addMessage = "\(AppDelegate.shared.addMessage(stringText, to: self.conversation!, sender: userReference, type: .text, date: message?.date))"
    self.tableObjects.append(addMessage)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.tableObjects.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    textField.text = nil
}
```

Comment: add a completion block then.

        self.tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: {
            (result) in
            self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        })

Comment: I just found a crash in my production app, spent the time to download and symbolocate, found this same exception, and found this solution. I hadn't put scrollToRow() on the main thread. (It's rare since scrollToRow() is only called when [self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows containsObject:indexPath] is false.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are scrolling the tableview before loading it.
You have to reload the tableview before scrolling it